# Janusgraph - efficient way to check and get edge between two vertices

Tags: scala, graph-databases, gremlin, janusgraph

I was trying to explore a janusgraph using Scala.

So, for given vertices, v1 and v2, I wanted to if out if there exists a directed edge from v1 to v2 with a particular property value and retrieve that edge.

In gremlin, we usually do a,

`g.V(v1).outE().where(otherV().is(v2)).hasNext()` to check if the edge exists and
`ed = g.V(v1).outE().where(otherV().is(v2)).next()` to get the edge.

So, what is the corresponding query in scala? Can't seem to use `otherV()` in a similar manner.

Thanks.

Comment: is there an error with `otherV()`?

Comment: How do you call that?
Directly calling `otherV()` throws a compile error. It is a function of the Traversal class as far as I know. How do I call it?

Answer (score 5):

`otherV()` in the context you are using it, is an [anonymous traversal](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/tutorials/gremlins-anatomy/#_anonymous_traversals) which is spawned from the `__` class. Either statically import `otherV()` from that class (which is what the gremlin console does) or just refer to it in full:

```
g.V(v1).outE().where(__.otherV().is(v2)).hasNext()
```

Comment: which index should be created to make this query run faster?

Comment: I don't think you can make `otherV()` run faster short of indices (and filters on those indices) on `outE()` so that you reduce the number of possible `otherV()` to filter on. Actually, as I re-read this question/answer, I wonder why `otherV()` is even used. `inV()` should be sufficient and potentially faster. You only need `otherV()` when you traverse `bothE()` and don't know which vertex you can from.